# How does spread operator work in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, syntax, operators, spread, fluttermap

I am following a Flutter tutorial that I can't understand this part:

```
class CartItem {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int quantity;
  final double price;

  CartItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.price,
  });
}

class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, CartItem> _items = {};

  Map<String, CartItem> get items {
    return {..._items};
  }
}

void addItem(
  String productId,
  double price,
  String title,
) {
  if (_items.containsKey(productId)) {
    // change quantity...
    _items.update(
      productId,
      (existingCartItem) => CartItem(
        id: existingCartItem.id,
        title: existingCartItem.title,
        price: existingCartItem.price,
        quantity: existingCartItem.quantity + 1,
      ),
    );
  } else {
    _items.putIfAbsent(
      productId,
      () => CartItem(
        id: DateTime.now().toString(),
        title: title,
        price: price,
        quantity: 1,
      ),
    );
  }
  notifyListeners();
}
```

I can't understand what `_items` look like? Also `..._items` and `{..._items}`?

Generally I can't understand the difference between these 3 variables and how each of them look like?

Answer (score 1):

... represents content of set or list
for example:

```
var list = [1,2,3,4];
var newList = [...list, 5] //eqals to [1,2,3,4,5]
var newNewList = [list] //syntax error
```

and ... inside curly brace means it assigns its values as json object's elements.

```
[
  {
    "id": existingCartItem.id,
    "title": existingCartItem.title,
    "price": existingCartItem.price,
    "quantity": existingCartItem.quantity + 1,
  },
  {
    ...
  },
]
```

Comment: Why I can't `print(..._items)` but I can `print(_items)` or `print({..._items})`?

Comment: Also I can't understand why did you put the `Map` inside a `List`?

Answer (score 1):

`_items` is declared here:

```
Map<String, CartItem> _items = {};
```

`..._items` is used only in `{..._items}`, which is creating a new Map. The contents of the Map come from creating a list that consists of key:value pairs (entries) from the current contents of `_items`, and in precisely the right shape that they will essentially end up as a "shallow copy" of the original data. This is to protect the value being returned from being mutated to affect the original data.

For details, look at [the feature specification for spreads (and collection literal if/for)](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.3/unified-collections/feature-specification.md), and [the motivation behind it](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.3/spread-collections/feature-specification.md).

Comment: Why I can't `print(..._items)` but I can `print(_items)` or `print({..._items})`?

Comment: the first one is not within a collection literal.